# $f(x, y(x))=0$ Show that $y'=-\frac{\partial f / \partial x}{\partial f/ \partial y}.$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

A relationship of the form $f(x, y(x))=0$ defines y implicitly. It is possible to find $y'(x)$ at points $x$ where $f$ is differentiable and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \neq 0.$ Show that at such points $y'=-\frac{\partial f / \partial x}{\partial f/ \partial y}.$

My understanding is that using the chain rule $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{ \partial y}y'$. Solving this we get $y'=\frac{\partial f / \partial x}{\partial f/ \partial y}$. I am not clear where the negative in the answer is coming from?

Comment: What have you tried? Also missing context, such as methods you've learned to approach this..

Comment: You applied chain rule wrongly - $f$ have $2$ variables.

Answer (score 1):

First step
$$\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$